# Time elapsed between first and second record

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My objective is to find the amount of time that has elapsed in between the first time a user used a service and the second time a user used the service.  Users who have only used the service once should be excluded.

For example, I have a sample dataset `test`:

```
> test
            start_time user_id
1  2018-01-17 22:10:21       1
2  2018-01-17 22:10:08       2
3  2018-01-18 07:02:36       3
4  2018-01-18 07:24:18       4
5  2018-01-18 15:08:45       2
6  2018-01-18 15:26:57       1
7  2018-01-18 15:37:47       1
8  2018-01-18 20:12:43       3
9  2018-01-18 20:01:08       2
10 2018-01-18 22:42:02       2
```

I am able to go one by one with `difftime`:

```
output$time_lapse[1] <- abs(difftime(test$start_time[1], test$start_time[6]))
```

But this will take a long time on a large dataset.  How could one iterate with `data.table` or `dplyr` ?

The output would be in hours as below, from the test dataset above:

```
> output
  user_id time_lapse
1       1   17.27667
2       2   16.97694
3       3   13.16861
4       4         NA
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!  Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(start_time = structure(c(1516255821, 1516255808, 
1516287756, 1516289058, 1516316925, 1516318017, 1516318667, 1516335163, 
1516334468, 1516344122), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2)), .Names = c("start_time", 
"user_id"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `data.table` method

```
library(data.table)
test <- structure(list(start_time = structure(c(1516255821, 1516255808, 
                                               1516287756, 1516289058, 1516316925, 1516318017, 1516318667, 1516335163, 
                                               1516334468, 1516344122), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                      user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2)), .Names = c("start_time", 
                                                                             "user_id"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(test)
test[, .(time_lapse = difftime(start_time[2], start_time[1])), by = user_id]


    #    user_id     time_lapse
    # 1:       1 17.27667 hours
    # 2:       2 16.97694 hours
    # 3:       3 13.16861 hours
    # 4:       4       NA hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with `dplyr`

```
df = structure(list(start_time = structure(c(1516255821, 1516255808, 
                                        1516287756, 1516289058, 1516316925, 1516318017, 1516318667, 1516335163, 
                                        1516334468, 1516344122), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
               user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2)), .Names = c("start_time", 
                                                                      "user_id"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  mutate(dif = difftime(start_time,lag(start_time),units = "hours")) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==2)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   user_id [3]
           start_time user_id            dif
               <dttm>   <dbl>         <time>
1 2018-01-18 21:08:45       2 16.97694 hours
2 2018-01-18 21:26:57       1 17.27667 hours
3 2018-01-19 02:12:43       3 13.16861 hours
```